# Como converter byte para boolean[8] e converter de volta?

Tags: java, conversão, byte, booleano

Preciso gravar alguns **booleans** em um Arquivo, e depois recuperá-los. Eu consigo gravar e ler um ou mais **bytes** com as Classes `java.io.FileInputStream` e `java.io.FileOutputStream`, por isso, preciso fazer a conversão de 1 byte para um array de 8 booleans, e, a conversão de um array de 8 booleans para 1 byte, assim:

```
public static boolean[] byteToBooleanArray(byte b) {
    boolean[] array = new boolean[8];
    //O que colocar aqui?
    return array;
}

public static byte booleanArrayToByte(boolean[] array) {
    if (array.length != 8) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    byte b;
    //O que colocar aqui?
    return b;
}
```

**Nota:** gostaria de não ter que baixar uma biblioteca.

Comment: Problema interessante o seu. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Julgo que existirão várias formas de o fazer.
A que me ocorre agora é:

- Usar a expressão `(b & (1 << i)) != 0` para verificar se o bit na posição `i` do byte está "setado" e guardar o resultado na respectiva posição no array.

  ```
  public static boolean[] byteToBooleanArray(byte b) {
      boolean[] array = new boolean[8];
      for (int i=0; i<8 ;i++){
          array[i] = (b & (1 << i)) != 0;
      }
      return array;
  }
  ```
- Usar a expressão `b |= 1 << i` para "setar", no byte, o bit na posição que corresponde à posição `i` do array, caso o seu valor seja `true`.

  ```
  public static byte booleanArrayToByte(boolean[] array) {
      if (array.length != 8) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      byte b = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
          if (array[i]) {
              b |= 1 << i;
          }
      }
      return b;
  }
  ```

Comment: Muito obrigado @ramaral, eu testei seu código contra outros que acabei encontrando no SOen, para ver se dava a mesma saída pra mesma entrada. Descobri que seu "byteToBooleanArray()" dá o mesmo resultado do algoritmo corrigido [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894023/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-byte-to-a-boolean-array-in-java). Mas o mais incrivel, é que seu "booleanArrayToByte()" ***não deu o mesmo resultado*** da resposta aceita (com 5 votos!) [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32048206/7711016); mas é quase igual ao da outra [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32048436/7711016)

Comment: pelos meus testes é o seu "booleanArrayToByte()" que está certo. muito obrigado!

Comment: O que acontece nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048064/java-simple-boolean-to-byte-conversion/32048206#32048206) é que os valores estão invertidos: a posição 0 do array corresponde ao bit 8. Uma forma de testar é se ao partir de um determinado valor, após usar os dois métodos, chega ao mesmo valor.

Comment: @Douglas eu estava elaborando uma resposta baseada nessa resposta também, até perceber o que o ramaral explicou acima, que ele inverte o array de booleans ao converter. Sem contar que ele fixa o tamanho de um array recebido em 8, no seu caso nem é um problema, mas fica meio estranho, uma vez que o método não conhece o parametro até ele ser recebido.

Answer (score 4):

Creio que a conversão do array de booleans para um único byte envolve muitas operações de movimentação bite a bite (arithmetic shift), as quais normalmente são complexas de entender e manter, a não ser que você possua larga experiência com isso. Provavelmente o resultado mas simples é um array de bytes, o qual você pode usar no stream que desejar, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
@Test
public void testConvert() throws Exception{
    boolean[] esperado = {true, false, false, true, true, false, false, true};
    byte[] result;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

    oos.writeObject(esperado);

    oos.flush(); 
    result = bos.toByteArray();

    Assert.assertNotNull(result);
    System.out.println(result.length);

    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(result));

    boolean[] obtido = (boolean[]) ois.readObject();

    for(int i = 0; i < esperado.length; i++){
        Assert.assertEquals(esperado[i], obtido[i]);
        System.out.println(esperado[i]);
    }
}
```

Lembrando que ao invés do ByteArrayOutputStream você pode utilizar o FileOutputStream diretamente ou, como dito anteriormente, qualquer tipo de stream que desejar.

No entanto, apesar de não saber exatamente para que você necessita desta solução, creio que possam haver formas mais elegantes de resolver o seu problema.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Onde você converte o array de boolean para um unico byte nesse código? Estou vendo que está convertendo em um array de byte, dando resultado diferente do que provavelmente o autor espera.

Comment: É o que diz o texto anterior ao código, bom final de semana.

Comment: Certo, mas no código da outra resposta mostra que é possivel sim :), de qualquer forma, não invalida sua resposta.